# simple_one_for_one start_child() returns already_started

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor, simple-one-for-one

I have a supervisor which should start `simple_one_for_one` workers. When I call `start_child()` for the first time, everything goes excellent. But, when I do it the second time, I get `{error,{already_started,<0.71.0>}}`. Why would `simple_one_for_one` supervisor return me a `already_started`? What am I missing?

Here is the code: [supervisor](https://github.com/egon-sim/egon_server/blob/master/src/es_interface_dispatcher.erl), [worker](https://github.com/egon-sim/egon_server/blob/master/src/es_interface_server.erl).

Comment: You're going to be awfully confused with your gen server handling messages by spawning a child to send a message to itself and then blocking while waiting to receive that message.

Comment: Why? I do the work in separate child to prevent gen_server from crashing. Is that a bad thing to do? Advice would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: Would it be a catastrophe if the gen_server crashed? It will be restarted by the supervisor. If you are worried about errors then wrap the call instead with a `try ... catch ... end`. While processes are cheap there is no gain in creating them unnecessarily and here there is no concurrency.

Comment: Can you post the code here? If that link ever breaks, this question will be useless.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you are registering a (local) name for your gen_server.  once you start one, you can not start another one with the same name.

if you use gen_server:start_link/3 instead, removing the first argument from your current gen_server:start_link/4 call, you should be able to start up more than one.